# map foldLeft type mismatch found Int required String

Tags: scala, dictionary

I have a map `m` of this form 
`m = [(b, 2), (c,3), (d,4)]`

I am trying to increment the count like this using foldLeft

```
m.foldLeft(Map[Char, Int]())((r,c) => r + (c._1 -> r.getOrElse(c._1, 0).t
oInt+1))
```

I get an error like this

```
<console>:10: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int(1)
 required: String
              m.foldLeft(Map[Char, Int]())((r,c) => r + (c._1 -> r.getOrElse(c._
1, 0).toInt+1))

            ^
```

How do I fix this issue? If I don't put +1 I get the values from the map.

Comment: Okay found the issue, sorry for the troubles

Comment: I don't think there's any need for the `getOrElse`. By definition you'll only get keys that are known to be in the `Map`.

Comment: Thanks @RandallSchulz you are right. No need for the getOrElse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m.foldLeft(Map[Char, Int]())((r,c) => r + (c._1 -> (r.getOrElse(c._1, 0).toInt+1)))
```

I had to enclose `c._1 -> (r.getOrElse(c._1, 0).toInt + 1)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure `foldLeft` is the operation you want. If you want to add one to each of the values in the map, then this will do:

```
scala> m.map(xs => xs._1 -> (xs._2 + 1))
res25: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(b -> 3, c -> 4, d -> 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
m.foldLeft(Map[Char, Int]())((r,c) => r + (c._1 -> (r.getOrElse(c._1, 0).toInt+1)))
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, got lost in the curlies